# Input String Is Encoded, Need The Original String - Java Code

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I have a REST web service that takes input in the form of JSON (as multipart form data).

```
@POST
@Consumes ({"application/ds-json",MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,"text/html",MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})
@Produces({ text_html, "application/ds-json" })
@Path("/abc")
public Response abc(@Context HttpServletRequest req, @Context HttpServletResponse response){
           .
           .
           .
           .
     String strInput = inputJSON.getString("data");
           .
           .
           .
}
```

The input JSON that I send is `{"data":"Sécurité"}` while the value of string `strInput` I get is `SÃ©curitÃ©`

I tried `java.net.URLDecoder.decode(strInput, "iso-8859-1")` to decode it back to its original character, but failed.

I also tried `String strInput = new String((inputJSON.getString("data")).getBytes(), "iso-8859-1");` in anticipation that the incoming characters will get stored in the variable `strInput` as per requirement, but failed.

I feel totally lost here. Can someone help?

---

EDIT:

To be more clear, below is how exactly I'm sending the JSON to this service(for testing purpose only):

1. I have created an HTML page that can send POST requests to the web service

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>

<body>

  <form action="http://localhost:8080/xxxx/abc" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    JSON:
    <input type="text" name="data">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

2. In the page, I enter the text as `Sécurité`

Comment: Try UTF-8 or UTF-16, maybe?

Comment: Where do you see the wrong encoded String? In your IDE, DB or somewhere else?

Comment: in my IDE, later I am sending an email notification with this string used as the subject line in the email. There also it shows as the same `SÃ©curitÃ©`

Comment: What you're seeing is UTF-8 data decoded as ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @Kayaman Yes, you are very much correct and I tested that in a separate test class. But in my current case(the web service), the data that I'm getting as input seems to be corrupted somehow. I tried printing bytes of both **the input** and **the expected string**:

**byte[] s = strInput.getBytes("UTF-8");
byte[] s1 = "Sécurité".getBytes("UTF-8");**

their result:

s = [83, -61, -125, -62, -87, 99, 117, 114, 105, 116, -61, -125, -62, -87]
s1 = [83, -61, -87, 99, 117, 114, 105, 116, -61, -87]

both these should have been same, but I'm getting extra bytes {-125, -62}

Comment: Add a `accept-charset="UTF-8"` on your form tag and see if the bytes are properly sent. Then you should have the same results from your `getBytes("UTF-8");` test.

Comment: That doesn't help either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone, I somehow managed to resolve this issue and @kayaman's comment helped me reach here

> What you're seeing is UTF-8 data decoded as ISO-8859-1. – Kayaman

I just converted the input string `strInput` to bytes as per `ISO-8859-1` encoding and again created the new string as per `UTF-8` encoding. This did the job for me.

```
byte[] inputBytes = strInput.getBytes("iso-8859-1");
strInput = new String(inputBytes, "UTF-8");
```

Earlier I was fetching bytes of the input string as `byte[] inputBytes = strInput.getBytes();` which by default was returning me `UTF-8` decoded bytes which was having extra bytes than what I had expected(I mentioned that to @Kayaman):

> @Kayaman Yes, you are very much correct and I tested that in a separate test class. But in my current case(the web service), the data that I'm getting as input seems to be corrupted somehow. I tried printing bytes of both the input and the expected string: byte[] s = strInput.getBytes("UTF-8"); byte[] s1 = "Sécurité".getBytes("UTF-8"); their result: s = [83, -61, -125, -62, -87, 99, 117, 114, 105, 116, -61, -125, -62, -87] s1 = [83, -61, -87, 99, 117, 114, 105, 116, -61, -87] both these should have been same, but I'm getting extra bytes {-125, -62} – Ankan Priya

however, as the string was in `ISO-8859-1` encoded form, I needed to get the bytes using the same decoding scheme and it worked(see code snippet above)

Answer (score 1):

All Java characters are stored in memory using `UTF-16`. The problem comes from transferred bytes. You wrote

> I send is `{"data":"Sécurité"}`

It's just a representation, it provides no information about byte representation used to transfer the text. If used representation is not part of the response, the receiver can't invent it. In case of missing encoding, both sender and consumer must rely on same convention. For example, some protocol have defaults but it means that both sender and receiver respects the standard default and they also have to be in sync with the specification (default encodings change over time).

From your specific problem, when your Java request processor has received the sent bytes, it has convert it into Java `char` using a [Charset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/nio/charset/Charset.html). Unsupported bytes are just lost in this conversion.

The possible solutions :

1. Makes the sender ALWAYS specifiy used encoding
2. Adds a request filter that guess a default encoding based on some request metadata (ie `User-Agent`)
3. Stop using IE (as far as I know IE8 does wrong things with encoding, especially with XHR)

Note: A `must-read` article : [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in Consumes parameters:

> +";charset=utf-8"

Por example:

> MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON +";charset=utf-8"

I use it, but with the output and works fine.

Comment: I tried this but did not really help. Whole issue remained exactly same.